# Smarty display database field name not value

Tags: php, smarty

In smarty I would like to display the db field name  (column name.) Is this possible? I am only able to get the value.

```
{foreach from=$test key=key item=item}
{$item.column_name}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nested array.

```
{foreach from=$test key=key item=item}
    {foreach from=$item key=k item=i}
        {$k}: {$i} {* returns 'column_name: value' *}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
{section name=item loop=$test}
{$test[item].column_name}
{/section}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Smarty` is just a template language. It doesn't know (and it doesn't care) about databases, field names and such. You use its method `assign()` into the `PHP` code to let it know about some data using a name you provide. Think of such data as a `template variable`. Then you use the template language features to format and display the data you set in the template variables in the `PHP` code. It's up to you what data you pass from the code to the template and how you organize that data.

Read the paragraph above again and again until you find the answer to your question.

The answer is very simple: if the field names are included in a data structure that was `assign()`-ed to `Smarty` then you have them available in the template to be displayed.

Sometimes they are the keys of the arrays you are displaying; other times you put them in a different variable; it depends. Use `print_r()` before assigning a variable to `Smarty` to find about its structure and know how to use it in the template.

**Example:**

The `PHP` code:

```
$resultset = $db->query("SELECT id, username, email FROM users WHERE username = 'foo'");
$row = $resultset->fetchAssoc();

$smarty->assign('userInfo', $row);
// For debug purposes only; remove it after first use
print_r($row);
```

The output of `print_r($row);`:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1001
    [username] => 'foo'
    [email] => 'foo@bar.baz'
)
```

The template:

```
<ul>
{foreach from=userInfo key=field item=value}
    <li><b>{$field}</b>: {$value}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

The output in the browser (kind of):

> - **id**: 1001
> - **username**: foo
> - **email**: foo@bar.baz